# How can I add background image to radiobutton in wpf?

Tags: wpf, image, background, controls, radio-button

How can I add an image to the radiobutton in WPF dynamically? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  myRadioButton.Content
      = new Image()
                {
                   Source =
                       (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFrom(
                         "Images/pic.png") as
                             ImageSource
                };
```

This code will load an image "pic.png" in a radio button from local "Images" folder from same assembly.

Comment: hello! and can the images be centered vertically with the radio? I try VerticalAlignment on the image and radio button but it did not work :S

Comment: found the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008776/why-arent-my-wpf-radio-buttons-vertically-aligned-to-the-center using VerticalContentAlignment