# Why aren't my WPF radio buttons vertically aligned to the center?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project where I'm trying to use radio buttons to determine which `TextBox` input to use. When I run it, though, the radio button itself is aligned to the top of the container, and I cannot find any sort of alignment property that affects it. Is this behavior expected? I've been searching for answers but everything seems to be asking how to align the radio button vertically. My assumption is that it's related to how I have it nested in other controls, but how can I make it work without changing too much?

This is the xaml relevant to the radio buttons:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0">
  <RadioButton HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsChecked="True">
    <xctk:TimePicker Name="TimePickerBox" Margin="0" Format="LongTime"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
  </RadioButton>
  <RadioButton Margin="0,5,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBox Name="Hours" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">0</TextBox>
      <Label>Hours</Label>
      <TextBox Name="Minutes" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">0</TextBox>
      <Label>Minutes</Label>
      <TextBox Name="Seconds" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">0</TextBox>
      <Label>Seconds</Label>
    </StackPanel>
  </RadioButton>
// ...
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Radio button alignment]

How can I get the radio buttons to be centered vertically?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Set **`VerticalContentAlignment`** as **`Center`** for RadioButton:

```
<RadioButton Margin="0,5,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
  .....
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Is there a rationale for why VerticalAlignment is insufficient? Unlike things like listboxes there is no "content" in a radio button. Is this just a WPF oddity?

Comment: `VerticalAlignment` will align control in relation to its containing parent whereas `VerticalContentAlignment` will align the content in relation to itself.  And you are right regarding radio button doesn't have content. If you look at default template of radioButton, you will notice VerticalAlignment of Border is mapped to VerticalContentAlignment. `VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"`

Answer (score 5):

On both `RadioButton` elements, try adding `VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"`.  I did that in a test project and it seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really remember what `DockPanel.Dock` does, but try setting `StackPanel`'s `VerticalAligment` to `Center`, and if it doesn't help also set the `DockPanel.Dock` to `Center`

```
<RadioButton Margin="0,5,0,0" DockPanel.Dock="Center">
  <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox Name="Hours" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">0</TextBox>
    <Label>Hours</Label>
    <TextBox Name="Minutes" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">0</TextBox>
    <Label>Minutes</Label>
    <TextBox Name="Seconds" Width="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">0</TextBox>
    <Label>Seconds</Label>
  </StackPanel>
</RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your XAML and it does exactly what you want it to do. So it seems there might be another reason to this.
Note that a radioButtons Bullet will always align to the first line of a textblock inside of it.
For further reading see here:
[How do I make a RadioButton's Bullet align top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533753/how-do-i-make-a-radiobuttons-bullet-align-top) for an explanation.