# XAML UWP Radio button icon aligned to center

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

Here's my code:

```
<StackPanel Name="stackPanelMain" Orientation="Vertical">
    <RadioButton Content="Work" Style="{StaticResource Rick_RadioButtonOption}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Non-Work" Style="{StaticResource Rick_RadioButtonOption}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's the style:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="Rick_RadioButtonOption">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="27" />
</Style>
```

I've increased the padding so it is more obvious what is happeing. The text is centred as expected/required but the actual radio button remains top-left:

[image: Current format]

How do I get the radio button centred vertically and to the right slightly? I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008776/why-arent-my-wpf-radio-buttons-vertically-aligned-to-the-center) but it doesn't work for my situation.

EDIT
As per @asitis  request - this is what I get if I set these 2 properties in the style:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
```

[image: Style Change result]

Comment: I tried with your style and xaml. Works as expected. But how will you get this height with the above xaml ?

Comment: @asitis I'm new to xaml. The height of the element is set using the padding. Is this what you mean? I don't need a specific height. just a bit of spacing around the text/radio button

Comment: I used the same xaml & style. And I am getting the correct aligned items. But height fits the radio button

Comment: Can you share the exact code, which produce the design in the image?

Comment: The above is pretty much all the code for that page - just the standard `Page` tag missing

Comment: So Can you set  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" /> in the style ?

Comment: Just added the result of these styles to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101076/discussion-between-asitis-and-rick).

Comment: It is very strange. How did the color of ellipse getting black after setting foreground & background color to red ?

Comment: hmmm... not sure - perhaps I have a conflicting style somehow? when I set a style does it completely override any other style or does it only override styles that are specifically set?

Comment: where did you register your Rick_RadioButtonOption style ? Inside Page resources itself or in any global resource file ?

Comment: Ok. Lets copy & paste it under Page.Resources. There might be some conflicts. Or check whether you are using any other style in the project. Also check the code behind c#

Comment: ok, I've done that - still the same. I changed the font size to ensure it is using the <Page.Resouce> style and it is.

Comment: Create a new sample project & copy your code & run

Answer (score 1):

This can be done just with modifying of the default style of a `RadioButton`. You can use the `LiveVisualTree` to see the default style of `RadioButton`, a `RadioButton` is actually a `Grid`, which contains another `Grid` with 3 `Ellipses` and a `ContentPresenter` like this:
[image]

Using the [Live Visual Tree](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) can get a real-time view of your running XAML code, you can use this tool in VS2015 when you debug the app, open it at the left side of vs2015:
[image]
If you edit a copy of the `RadioButton`'s default style, you can see the `Grid` with 3 `Ellipses` is like this `<Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top">`. This is the reason why your `Ellipses` is on the top. So you can customize the style like this:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
    <!--<Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,6,0,0" />-->
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="27" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
    ......
    <Grid Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Center">
       <Ellipse x:Name="OuterEllipse" Height="20" Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20" />
       <Ellipse x:Name="CheckOuterEllipse" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" Height="20" Opacity="0" Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAccentBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="20" />
       <Ellipse x:Name="CheckGlyph" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" Height="10" Opacity="0" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="10" />
    </Grid>
    ......
</Style>
```

By the way, to modify the template of `RadioButton`, we can select the "**[RadioButton]**" in "**Document Outline**" and right click, then select "**Edit Template**" →  "**Edit a Copy...**".

Comment: Cool, I'll give this a go later on today and let you know how I get on. I never thought something so simple would have such a complex solution !

Answer (score 0):

set `verticalAligment` `property` as a `center` for `RadioButton` ,
Ellipse in the Radiobutton is always on top, To solve this problem, you must change the template

```
   <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="27" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Border x:Name="radioButtonBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="100" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1,1,2,1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid x:Name="markGrid" Margin="2">
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="optionMark" Fill="#FF212121" MinWidth="6" MinHeight="6" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                                        <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="#FFF3F9FF"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="#FF5593FF"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="#FF212121"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="#FFE6E6E6"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="#FFBCBCBC"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="#FF707070"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="#FFD9ECFF"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="radioButtonBorder" Value="#FF3C77DD"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="#FF212121"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0.56"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Setting this doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: `VerticalAligment` should give the answer Otherwise, Use the style in the Answer

Answer (score 0):

add in page or application resources this control template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="RadioButtonControlTemplate1" TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAccentBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="0"
                                    Duration="0" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckOuterEllipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1"
                                    Duration="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="32" >
                    <Ellipse x:Name="OuterEllipse"
                        Width="20"
                        Height="20"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
                    <Ellipse x:Name="CheckOuterEllipse"
                        Width="20"
                        Height="20"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltAccentBrush}"
                        Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource RadioButtonBorderThemeThickness}"
                             />
                    <Ellipse x:Name="CheckGlyph"
                        Width="10"
                        Height="10"
                        UseLayoutRounding="False"
                        Opacity="0"
                        Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                    ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

and apply it to your radio button in this manner:

```
<RadioButton Content="Non-Work" Style="{StaticResource Rick_RadioButtonOption}" Template="{StaticResource RadioButtonControlTemplate1}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later and let you know the result

Answer (score 0):

`Margin` and `Padding` have 4 values: `Left`, `Top`, `Right`, `Bottom`. If you use one value only, all four values will be set identical. To move a `RadioButton` to the right you must increase the `Left` `Margin` value. You should also use `TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"`:

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" x:Key="Rick_RadioButtonOption">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5,5,5" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="27" />
    </Style>
```