# Add image to the radio button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
  <StackPanel Name="StpAddDel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
    <RadioButton Name="rdbactive" Content="Active" GroupName="actinact" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Width="50" Height="15" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <RadioButton Name="rdbinactive" Content="InActive" GroupName="actinact" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Width="60" Height="15" Foreground="Blue"/>
    <Button Name="BtnAdd"  Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" Template="{StaticResource AddImgBtnTemplate}" />
    <Button Name="BtnDel" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" Template="{StaticResource DelImgBtnTemplate}" />
  </StackPanel>
```

This is the code available in my wpf window. How can I add the images to these radio buttons in MVVM.

Comment: What images? What piece needs to be bound (for MVVM)? What problem are you having doing this? Can you show a screenshot of what you *want* it to be like?

Comment: MVVM has nothing to do with this, since this is 100% view related.

Comment: @sparta93 That's HTML+CSS, this is WPF and XAML

Comment: suppose for example for button we add some image in that sameway my user want to add some image to the radio button

Comment: @almulo whoops, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767667/how-can-i-add-background-image-to-radiobutton-in-wpf

Comment: Almost, @sparta93, but that's for Button and this is for RadioButton haha Maybe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573358/radiobutton-and-image ?

Comment: @trinadh Have you tried simply setting the `Content` property of the RadioButtons to an image? Something like `Content="active.jpg"` or however your image is called.

Comment: can anyone please answer my below question pls...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987136/change-the-image-of-the-radio-button-after-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds a picture to the background of your radio button.

```
myRadioButton.Content = new Image()
{
Source = (new ImageSourceConverter()).ConvertFrom(
                         "Images/pic.png") as
                             ImageSource
};
```

Comment: hi sparta, can u pls answer my below question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032048/checkbox-disabling-and-enabling-in-wpf