# Change the image of the radio button after checked

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

```
<StackPanel Name="StpAddDel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5">
   <RadioButton Name="rdbactive" GroupName="actinact" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Width="50" Height="15" Foreground="Blue">
      <RadioButton.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                     <Grid>
                        <Image Source="c:\image.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                     </Grid>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </RadioButton.Style>
   </RadioButton>
   <RadioButton Name="rdbinactive" GroupName="actinact" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0" Width="60" Height="15" Foreground="Blue">
      <RadioButton.Style>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                     <Grid>
                        <Image Source="c:\image.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                     </Grid>
                  </ControlTemplate>
               </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
         </Style>
      </RadioButton.Style>
   </RadioButton>
   <Button Name="BtnAdd"  Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" Template="{StaticResource AddImgBtnTemplate}" />
   <Button Name="BtnDel" Height="20" Width="20" Margin="5,0" Template="{StaticResource DelImgBtnTemplate}" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the above code i have 2 radio button i put images on radio buttons , My requirement is i want to change the image of the radio button after it is checked, Please help me with this......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ControlTemplate.Triggers` for that

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
   <Grid>
       <Image x:Name="PART_Image" Source="c:\image.png" Width="32" Height="32"/>
       <ContentPresenter/>
   </Grid>
   <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
           <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Source" Value="new source"/>
       </Trigger>
   </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Give `Image` some name and change `Source` property of that control when `IsChecked` is true

**EDIT**

If you want to also "highlight" when mouse is over then you can add for example `DropShadowEffect` with another `Trigger`, this time when `IsMouseOver` is true

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="Yellow" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: hi can u pls give answer for my below question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007718/datagrid-select-row-image-change

Comment: hi dkozl, can u pls answer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31032048/checkbox-disabling-and-enabling-in-wpf